# Parse and extract all the HTML tags

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a requirement to parse and extract all the HTML tags starting with `<a href=""` and end with `"">`.

sample.csv

`<p class=""normal_(Web)"" align=""left""><span style=""font-family:Arial,Arial;font-size:10px;color:#000000"">First, </span><b><a href=""file:///C:/display/JITS/SDSSE+-+R12+User+Search""><span style=""font-family:Arial,Arial;font-size:10px;"">search</span></a></b><span style=""font-family:Arial,Arial;font-size:10px;color:#000000""> for the user.  If you don't find the account, then </span><b><a href=""file:///C:/display/JITS/SDSSE+-+Creating+Oracle+R12+Accounts""><span style=""font-family:Arial,Arial;font-size:10px;"">create</span></a></b><span style=""font-family:Arial,Arial;font-size:10px;color:#000000""> one.  Once you have an account to work with, then proceed.</span></p>`

Can you please help me with `awk` or `sed` command to print/log only the sub string including `<a href=""` and `"">`?
Output should be

`<a href=""file:///C:/display/JITS/SDSSE+-+R12+User+Search"">`

`<a href=""file:///C:/display/JITS/SDSSE+-+Creating+Oracle+R12+Accounts"">`

Comment: Update the exact output needed for your above input along with your own efforts to solve this

Comment: Changed the post accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

`sed -n 's/.*\(<a\ href=[^>]*>\).*/\1/p'`

This sed uses the `n` flag, which causes sed to print nothing by default, after this we use the substitution command to find the specified regex and replace it with the first capturing group, then the `p` modifier is used to print this regex.

In the regex we look for the first occurrence of `<a href=` and then match everything until `>`.

This does not work if there is another `>` in your tag.

Comment: Hi redxef, sorry i ran into issue with some lines that had multiple <a href , Can you please help. I have edited the actual post to print that line.

Comment: Add the `g` modifier (stands for global) to the end of the command (after the p). This will match multiple occurrences of pattern in a single line.

Comment: Sorry, this will not work because of the greedy regex expansion of `.*`

Comment: Thanks. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: One approach involves `tr`, just replace every comma with a newline, which makes the sed command work: `cat sample.csv | tr , '\n' | sed -n 's/.*\(<a\ href=[^>]*>\).*/\1/p'`

Answer (score 0):

@Varun: Try:

```
awk '{gsub(/<a href=|"|>/,"");print}'   Input_file
```

Here I am globally making substitution of strings like "a href", ">" and " then printing the value of the line.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, Thanks for prompt response. The command did not print the desired string. Here is the content of one line.                          <p class=""normal_(Web)"" align=""left""><u><a href=""file:///C:/display/JITS/SDSSE+-+Oracle+R12+Browser+Troubleshooting""><span style=""font-family: Arial,Arial; font-size: 10px; color: #0000ff;"">Oracle browser troubleshooting</span></a></u><span style=""font-family: Arial,Arial;</p>     And I want the output as <a href=""file:///C:/display/JITS/SDSSE+-+Oracle+R12+Browser+Troubleshooting"">

Comment: @Varun: Please post sample Input_file and expected output into your actual post with code tags as without code tags it is not clear at all.

Comment: Sorry for the confustion Ravinder. This is my first post in stackoverflow and still trying to understand the rules and code tags.